# Ruby inheritance of class and method in JDBC connection string

Tags: ruby, jdbc, db2, dashdb

I have the following code snippet that generates a JDBC connection string for various databases. In this case, Dash DB and IBM DB2. The following is the structure of the code I use to generate my connection string in DB2.

```
def connection_creation_information
  @connection_creation_information ||= Class.new(JDBCConnectionCreationInformation) do

    private

    def connection_string_primary_params(options)
      params = []

      params << "currentSchema=#{options[:schema] || options[:username]}"

      params << options[:jdbc_additional_params] if options[:jdbc_additional_params]

      params
    end

    def connection_string_scheme
      'db2'
    end

    def connection_string_params(options)
      super + ';'
    end

    def primary_param_separator
      ';'
    end

    def base_separator
      ':'
    end
  end.new
end
```

Now, DashDB uses `defaultSchema` to define the default schema, while in DB2, it uses `currentSchema`. I am trying to minimize redundant code as much as possible, so right now, Dash DB's code inherits from DB2 using `class HTDialectDashDB < HTDialectDB2` and override the one line/method that matters -- `connection_string_primary_params()`

In my Dash DB class, I am doing the following:

```
def connection_creation_information
  @connection_creation_information ||= Class.new(JDBCConnectionCreationInformation) do

    private

    def connection_string_primary_params(options)
      params = []

      params << "defaultSchema=#{options[:schema] || options[:username]}"

      params << options[:jdbc_additional_params] if options[:jdbc_additional_params]

      params
    end

  end.new
end
```

However, errors are being thrown that I must implement the four other methods described in the DB2 code, which I want to avoid, because it's just redundant code.

What can I do in this case?

Comment: Can't help with Ruby, but dashDB, being basically DB2, should be fine with the standard DB2 connection string properties.

Comment: You are right! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `currentSchema` for both Dash DB and DB2 works.